# When $P_n=\frac{3^n-1}{2}$, prove that $P_{qn}$ is not a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $P_n=\frac{3^n-1}{2}$, $q\in\mathbb N, q\neq 1$, then
$$ P_q \text{ is composite } \Leftrightarrow \forall n\in\mathbb N: P_{qn} \text{ is composite}$$

In other words, each $q$ you find, such that $P_q$ is not prime (e.g. $q=2,5,11,17,19$) gives you a class $P_{qn}$, which is never prime.

Comment: Try to prove that if some prime number $p$ divides $P_q$ then it also divides $P_{qn}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** $ 3^n-1$  divides $3^{q n}-1.$